# intellij - using the current active task in code templates

Tags: intellij-idea, jira

We are using JIRA as issue tracker, and intellij as IDE.
Intellij is connected with JIRA using the atlassian IDE connector.
When we start to work on some task, we activate the corresponding JIRA issue

Is there a way to configure the code templates such that when we create a new file, the current 'active' issue is referenced.  've been looking around but didn't find the righ $variable.